# Help migrating from robot_pose_ekf to robot_localization

Tags: localization, navigation, robot-localization, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am currently trying to migrate to robot_localization. I am using IMU and odometry data for the ekf_localization_node.
When running ekf_localization_node I get a tf error:

```
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_footprint" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
         at line 240 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.15/src/buffer_core.cpp
Error:   TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_footprint" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
         at line 253 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.15/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

[Here is a Bagfile](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09022578863517099218) I made containing IMU and Odometry data.
My cofing:

```
frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false
odom_frame: odom_combined            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom_combined           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

odom0: odom
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, true,
               true,  false, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 2
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: true
odom0_relative: false
odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5
odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1

imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: true
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

Any chance someone can help me figure this out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260671/help-migrating-from-robot_pose_ekf-to-robot_localization/) by [blasalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18941/blasalat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-05-04**:
Please post sample messages for each EKF input. Also, post any static transforms you are publishing.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-15**:
It seems like you haven't specified a `map_frame` parameter.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-07-25**:
It defaults to `map`. Did you ever solve this? If so, can we close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, sorry for responding so late. The error occurred due to nan values in my odom messages.

---

Originally posted by [blasalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18941/blasalat/) with karma: 51 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-05-15**:
the same problem for me

please help me

thank you in advance